# SVG animated background stops about half way scrolled down

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, svg

test.html:

```
<body style="background-image:url(test.svg);background-size:cover">
    <div style="height:2000px"> Hello! </div>
</body>
```

test.svg (taken from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animate):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120" version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <rect x="10" y="10" width="100" height="100">
    <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="x" from="-100" to="120"
        dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </rect>
</svg>
```

When I scroll about half way down the page, the animation pauses (actually, stops refreshing). Not sure why. Can't find anything on it in SVG specification, or google chrome documents...

My browser version `Chromium 73.0.3683.86 Built on Ubuntu, running on LinuxMint 18.`

Comment: Does this happen in Firefox?

Comment: @RobertLongson It does not, interesting. I guess I found a chrome bug.

Comment: I've just reported this bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=959643

Answer (score 0):

it's a chromium thing i think, the browser thinks that the svg is outside ur screen so it pauses it to save resources, u can put a div inside the one with the background and give the second div a height: 100vh; and overflow: auto;